# How do I find a collection of nodes in HtmlAgilityPack using linq to xml?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml, html-agility-pack

I want to extract information from various websites. I am using HtmlAgilityPack and Linq to XML. So far I have managed to extract the value from a single node in a website by writing:

```
var q = document.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
        .Where(n => n.Name == "img" && n.Id == "GraphicalBoard001")
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

But I am really interested in the whole collection of img's that start with "GraphicalBoard". I tried something like:

```
var q2 = document.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
        .Where(n => n.Name == "img" && n.Id.Contains("GraphicalBoard"))
        .Select...
```

But it seems that linq doesn't like the Contains-method, since I lose the Select option in intellisense. How can I extract all the img-tags where the Id starts with "GraphicalBoard"?

Comment: You realize you didn't close the `Where()` call right?

Comment: Ahh.. That did help a bit. But how do I rewrite it so it returns a collection instead of the FirstOrDefault()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I extract all the img-tags where the Id starts with "GraphicalBoard"?

You had it already, just stop at the call to `Where()`.  The `Where()` call filters the collection by the items that satisfies the predicate.

Though you should write it so you filter through the `img` descendants, not all descendants.

```
var query = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
               .Where(img => img.Id.StartsWith("GraphicalBoard"));
```